# MySQL not inserting data into a table upon a file being uploaded

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a gallery system which creates entries per image in a table allowing the script to retrieve all images with certain values. At the moment I've managed to get the file upload to work although it's not inputting the file name and gallery id into my table - it's not creating a row at all. Below is the code, any help would be amazing :)! I've messed around with a few things although file uploads and the likes aren't really my forte.

```
<?php
require "common.php";
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","$username","$password");
mysql_select_db("$dbname", $con);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT id,title,date FROM galleries WHERE id = $id");
    if (!$query2) {
        echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($query2);
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("../galleries/images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "../galleries/images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      $file = '["file"]["name"]';
      $sql="INSERT INTO images (url, gallery)
        VALUES
  ('$_POST[$file]','$_POST[$id]')";
  header("Location: ../../../gallery.php?id=" . $row[0]); 
  die("Redirecting to: admin.php"); 
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you redirect and kill your script before you execute your query:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO images (url, gallery)
        VALUES
         ('$_POST[$file]','$_POST[$id]')";
header("Location: ../../../gallery.php?id=" . $row[0]); 
die("Redirecting to: admin.php");
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ nothing after this gets executed
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this query will never run
   ...
```

And you really should switch to PDO (or mysqli) and prepared statements to avoid sql injection problems.

Comment: Thank you! It's now inserting rows into the table, just need to work out a few bugs. I think I'll have a look into PDO.